# Nginx wordpress multi site rewrite rules for subdir install

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am trying to set the rewrite rules in NGINX and I currently have some set for
**location / {**
already for my main website on that domain.
I would like to insall wordpress in a different folder so my **location / {**
needs to be **location /page {**

I can't seem to set the rewrite rules up for this?
Any help would be great I have tried.

[Rewrite rules for wordpress 3.0 (multi-site) for nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278277/rewrite-rules-for-wordpress-3-0-multi-site-for-nginx)

Doesn't seem to work.

Using this < I can get the page to show up for each user but with no images, css all the other files needed. Its only in plain text.

```
location /page {
     root  /home/domain/public_html;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;

     if (!-e $request_filename ) {
        rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /page/1$ last;
     }
}
```

I need some rules that can be used for the /page location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small typo:

Rather than using:

```
rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /page/1$ last;
```

Please try:

```
rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /page/$1 last;
```

Regex captures value is `$1`, not in `1$` ;-)

You will need to change few more things. Here is a complete config - http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/wordpress-nginx-multisite-subdirectories-in-subdirectory-itself/